# Trouble allowing user to exit

Tags: java

I am simply trying to allow a user to exit program when they enter "Q"

but my program right now just takes "Q" as another input and runs the program. This is supposed to be a piglatin translator still working on the consonant cluster problem

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment_4_Piglatin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userWord = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("K. Caleb Swallow");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!");

        boolean run = true;
        while (run) {

            System.out.println("Please enter a word(or press Q to quit):");

            String firstLetter = "something";

            String word = userWord.next();


            firstLetter = Character.toString(word.charAt(0));


            if (firstLetter.equals("a") || firstLetter.equals("e") ||
                    firstLetter.equals("i") || firstLetter.equals("o")
                    || firstLetter.equals("u")) {
                System.out.println(word + "way");
            } else {
                System.out.println(word.substring(1) + firstLetter + "ay");
            }

            if (word.equals("Q")) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure it would make a difference or not but you can try moving your `if(word.equals("Q")` check up and put it right after `String word =...`

Comment: Yep that was it! strange i wouldn't think location would make a difference but it did thank you!!

Comment: Remember that just doing System.exit(0); is not really a nice way to close your program. Much better to use break; to escape the loop and nicely close the reader.

Comment: If you don't want to execute whole Pig Latin for `Q` then you need to move decision of exiting from application before that section but after reading value from scanner.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful `next()` is moving from one token to another. Since by default delimiter is one or more whitespace then it doesn't matter if we have `a  b` or `a\n\nb`, with `next()` scanner will move from `a` to `b` since ` ` or `\n\n` will be considered as single delimiter (regardless of how many whitespaces there is between tokens).

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Only method which uses different delimiter than `next()` (or `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()`, ...) is `nextLine()` which is why we see many question about it. But this doesn't look like the case here since there is no `nextLine()` in code posted by OP.

Comment: @Pshemo - Oops, sorry. I missed that point. I agree `next()` uses delimiters while checking for tokens, whereas `nextLine()` doesn't take newline into consideration (excludes that). I'll delete my old comments(been a long time since I worked on Java), nowadays practicing C#. Thanks, :)

Answer (score 1):

Try running this now. Slight modification in if-else statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment_4_Piglatin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userWord = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("K. Caleb Swallow");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!");

        boolean run = true;
        while (run) {

            System.out.println("Please enter a word(or press Q to quit):");
            String firstLetter = "something";
            String word = userWord.next();

            firstLetter = Character.toString(word.charAt(0));

            if (firstLetter.equals("a") || firstLetter.equals("e") || firstLetter.equals("i") || firstLetter.equals("o")
                || firstLetter.equals("u")) {
                System.out.println(word + "way");
            } else if (word.equals("Q")) {
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                System.out.println(word.substring(1) + firstLetter + "ay");
            }
        }
        userWord.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you just want to stop the execution when ever user give 'Q' or 'q' so you should stop JVM from running your application.Try this.

```
if(firstLetter.equals("Q") || firstLetter.equals("q")){
    System.exit(0);//static method for stopping the JVM from System class
}
```

Comment: or use equalsIgnoreCase :)

Comment: i think OP wants to stop when the literal word "Q" is entered

Comment: Not specifically "Q". Any string with first letter as "q" or "Q"